# Getting a value of int from edittext

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I am trying to get a value from the edittext then cast it to int so that I can process the value for a substraction/additon/and so on. Here is the code I use, but I keep getting crash using this code.

```
number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
angka = Integer.parseInt(number.getText().toString());
//my alternative code is like this : angka = Integer.parseInt(String.Valueof(number));
```

Please I need your help, thanks you so much

Comment: What is the error that you get when it crashes?

Comment: @tima no error, the app is just automatically closed

Comment: @AnthonyLauly surround the code block with try and catch. Hold the debuger, see the exception and post.

Comment: are you sure number variable contains a string that is a valid integer?

Comment: Attach the screenshot of your **logcat**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think when you run your program then edit text have no value that means it will return NULL and NULL can't be a Integer value so you must have to check Condition Like

`String editTextValue = number.getText().toString();
        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(editTextValue)){
            angka = Integer.parseInt(editTextValue);
        }`

I hope its work for you.

Comment: @Dear  Mandy8055, Rather than giving down vote cast let him try the solution.I think he is new in android.

Comment: this answer solve my problem, the problem is because when I debug the program, then my application will instantly read my edit text while my edit text is still NULL, thats why it keeps crashing, thank you @shahid17june

Comment: @Anthony Lauly Your most welcome dear. Happy Coding :)