# how to get number input type from edittext android studio

Tags: android, android-layout

I have problem here,my java code is

```
int num = Integer.parseInt(mark.getText().toString());
```

And my xml code is

```
android. InputType="number"
```

But i am still getting error saying that `"invalid int ="""`
Can anyone help me..i really really need help right now.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_adding_remove);
        parentLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent_linear_layout);

        final EditText mark = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etMark);
        EditText j = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etJam);
        TextView status = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tVGred);
        TextView pn = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvPnm);



        double  pointer;
        String grade;

       int num = Integer.parseInt(mark.getText().toString());

        if (num >= 90 && num <= 100) {
            grade = "A+";
            pointer = 4.00;
            status.setText(grade);
        }
        else if (num >= 80 && num <= 89) {
            grade = "A";
            pointer = 4.00;
            status.setText(grade);
        }
        else if (num >= 75 && num <= 79) {
            grade = "A-";
            pointer = 3.67;
            status.setText(grade);
        }
        else if (num >= 70 && num <= 74) {
            grade = "B+";
            pointer = 3.33;
            status.setText(grade);

        }
         else if (num >= 65 && num <= 69) {
            grade = "B";
            pointer = 3.00;
            status.setText(grade);
        }
        else if (num >= 60 && num <= 64) {
            grade = "B-";
            pointer = 2.67;
            status.setText(grade);
        }
        else if (num >= 55 && num <= 59) {
            grade = "C+";
            pointer = 2.33;
            status.setText(grade);
        }
        else if (num >= 50 && num <= 54) {
            grade = "C";
            pointer = 2.00;
            status.setText(grade);
        }
        else if (num >= 47 && num <= 49) {
            grade = "C-";
            pointer = 1.67;
            status.setText(grade);
        }
        else if (num >= 44 && num <= 46) {
            grade = "D+";
            pointer = 1.33;
            status.setText(grade);
        }
        else if (num >= 40 && num <= 43) {
            grade = "D";
            pointer = 1.00;
            status.setText(grade);
        }
        else
        {
            grade = "F";
            pointer = 0.00;
            status.setText(grade);
        }


   }
```

Comment: Where exactly are you calling int num = Integer.parseInt(mark.getText().toString());

Comment: Most likely you are checking  int num = Integer.parseInt(mark.getText().toString());  in your onCreate() method. The problem is that in onCreate() you have not editText and it is returning you an empty string. Add a button and add the above code to onlcicklistner. Edit the edit text and click the button. you will be good.

Comment: From onCreate My edittext code final Edittext mark= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etMark);

Comment: I already hv edit text field but i don't used any button.. Please help me,

Comment: Can you share the entire activity ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45650927/getting-a-value-of-int-from-edittext

Comment: """  is this int?

Comment: Please check before parsing whether its not empty

Comment: i want to return string but before return string value,i want to check mark and im using int @RajeshNasit

Comment: i hv upload my mainactivity.java up there@android_Muncher

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with

```
 int num = Integer.parseInt(mark.getText().toString());
```

Your code is try to get text From EDITTEXT But is contains "" when ActiVity Created. So Activity Throw error For `invalid Int` so you need to  add any Button So Activity Get String When Button click Trigger. But If You dont want to use any Button Use Enter Key As Trigger to Change Focus and get String Fri EditText like this.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int num =0;
    EditText mark;
    EditText j;
    TextView status,pn;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);


        mark = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt);
         j = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.jmark);
         status = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
         pn = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt1);


        final double[] pointer = new double[1];
        final String[] grade = new String[1];





        mark.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER == keyCode) {
                    j.requestFocus();
                    if(mark.getText().toString()!="")
                    num= Integer.parseInt(mark.getText().toString());
                    if (num >= 90 && num <= 100) {
                        grade[0] = "A+";
                        pointer[0] = 4.00;
                        status.setText(grade[0]);
                    }
                    else if (num >= 80 && num <= 89) {
                        grade[0] = "A";
                        pointer[0] = 4.00;
                        status.setText(grade[0]);
                    }
                    else if (num >= 75 && num <= 79) {
                        grade[0] = "A-";
                        pointer[0] = 3.67;
                        status.setText(grade[0]);
                    }
                    else if (num >= 70 && num <= 74) {
                        grade[0] = "B+";
                        pointer[0] = 3.33;
                        status.setText(grade[0]);

                    }
                    else if (num >= 65 && num <= 69) {
                        grade[0] = "B";
                        pointer[0] = 3.00;
                        status.setText(grade[0]);
                    }
                    else if (num >= 60 && num <= 64) {
                        grade[0] = "B-";
                        pointer[0] = 2.67;
                        status.setText(grade[0]);
                    }
                    else if (num >= 55 && num <= 59) {
                        grade[0] = "C+";
                        pointer[0] = 2.33;
                        status.setText(grade[0]);
                    }
                    else if (num >= 50 && num <= 54) {
                        grade[0] = "C";
                        pointer[0] = 2.00;
                        status.setText(grade[0]);
                    }
                    else if (num >= 47 && num <= 49) {
                        grade[0] = "C-";
                        pointer[0] = 1.67;
                        status.setText(grade[0]);
                    }
                    else if (num >= 44 && num <= 46) {
                        grade[0] = "D+";
                        pointer[0] = 1.33;
                        status.setText(grade[0]);
                    }
                    else if (num >= 40 && num <= 43) {
                        grade[0] = "D";
                        pointer[0] = 1.00;
                        status.setText(grade[0]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        grade[0] = "F";
                        pointer[0] = 0.00;
                        status.setText(grade[0]);
                    }

                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Make Sure you added   `android:singleLine="true"` i your xml file

Comment: what problem you are facing now?

Comment: May I know,  [0] means what?

Comment: its just indicate as an array. it is used in inner class so need to declare final one element array.

Comment: Actually I want to develop an gpa n cgpa calculator, im not good enough using array,when i used correct my code using your and i don't know how to change everything on my code...i did try and another error appear.... Is there another ways?  Im sorry if i ask too much.

Answer (score 0):

```
use this    
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/login_text_phone"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:digits="0123456789"
                android:maxLength="10" />
```

Comment: problem is with int num = Integer.parseInt(mark.getText().toString()); line not in xml

Answer (score 0):

```
try this 
int num = toInteger(mark.getText().toString());


    public static Integer toInteger(Object value) {
        if (value instanceof Integer) {
            return (Integer) value;
        } else if (value instanceof Number) {
            return ((Number) value).intValue();
        } else if (value instanceof String) {
            try {
                return (int) Double.parseDouble((String) value);
            } catch (NumberFormatException ignored) {
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```